# How can I just get the most important information about a document and some lines around the word I searched for in MarkLogic / Query Console?

Tags: javascript, pdf, search, marklogic, nosql

I am new to MarkLogic and already loaded and converted some PDFs as .xml files into my database.

My 10 PDFs are about 500 pages long each. If I search for a word in Query Console like this,

```
cts.search("Infrastructurefunctions")
```

I will see every document with the word `Infrastructurefunctions` in it with its whole body / content (about 500 pages). And you can't see where a new document begins.

My goal is to have a result like the results you get on Google:

- Only the name of the document
- And the word I searched for highlighted with some words around to get the context

Thanks you for helping me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `cts.search` (as well as all other cts functions) is a low-level tool. There are more abstract libraries that will work much better for you. For XQuery we have the `search:search` function and related ones. For JavaScript you have `JSearch`. I can highly recommend looking into those:

- Search API: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/search-api
- JSearch: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/javascript

HTH!

Comment: I tried out JSearch, but I always get this:


_[javascript] XDMP-MODNOTFOUND: var jsearch = require('/MarkLogic/jsearch.sjs'); -- Module /MarkLogic/jsearch.sjs not found_

Comment: It was introduced in 8.0-4, you need at least that version: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/relnotes/chap3#id_20318

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are libraries that can do this for you, but I always think it is fun/important to learn how to do some of this yourself. This gives you more flexibility.

So, from your results, have a look at : [cts:walk](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:walk)

The second example is a cute sample of what you may be considering.